# VBA customized filtering via Keyword over wide column-range

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to program a filtering option over a wide range of Excel-Columns. I tried to do it via Inputboxes and If/Then-sequence like bellow but for some reason it runs through to the final Else-statement "does not exist". It seems it isn't recognizing my input.

```
  Sub MultipleColumnsFilter()

  Range("N:N,U:U").ClearContents

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim myValue1 As String
  Dim myValue2 As String


  myValue1 = InputBox("Enter desired Column")
  myValue2 = InputBox("Enter Keyword in selected column")


If myValue1 = c Then

With Worksheets("pump").Range("C:C")
    .AutoFilter
     '** Use temporary column 1
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myValue2
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ElseIf myValue1 = d Then

 With Worksheets("pump").Range("D:D")
    .AutoFilter
     '** Use temporary column 1
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myValue2
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ElseIf myValue1 = E Then
 With Worksheets("pump").Range("E:E")
    .AutoFilter
     '** Use temporary column 1
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myValue2
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


ElseIf myValue1 = I Then
 With Worksheets("pump").Range("I:I")
    .AutoFilter
     '** Use temporary column 1
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myValue2
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else

MsgBox (" does not exist ")

End If
```

Ofcourse it would be even better to let go of the If-else structure and go over some kind of Range function including multiple columns for the desired filtering-area, but when I tried it, it didn't work either.
Any clues ?

Edit: Furthermore I would like to expand the functionality and use the same structure for filtering items OUT, depending on some keyords (myValue2).
How could this work? I changed the filtering part as follows

```
 .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>myValue2"
```

but this does not seem to work, it just runs through the script without error but also without any effect on the cells.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe `If LCase(myValue1) = "c" Then` (more universal solution coming soon below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the only problem, but

```
If myValue1 = c Then
```

c is considered to be an undeclared variable, hence c="", so this line actually means:

```
If myValue1 = "" Then
```

This applies to all your elseif statements too.

Just use quotation marks:

```
If myValue1 = "c" Then
```

Remember that by default, VBA is case sensitive in string comparison. So you will either have to add:

```
Option Compare Text
```

on the top of your module, above your first Sub, or you can use this format:

```
If UCase(myValue1) = "C" Then
```

Comment: Thanks ! Putting the " " around the letter worked out .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more universal solution to filtering an unknown column for an unknown text string.

```
Dim myValue1 As String, myValue2 As String, myColumn As Long

myValue1 = InputBox("Enter desired Column")
myValue2 = InputBox("Enter Keyword in selected column")

If IsNumeric(myValue1) Then
    myColumn = Range("R1C" & myValue1).Column
Else
    myColumn = Range(myValue1 & 1).Column
End If

With Worksheets("pump")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Columns(myColumn)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myValue2
    End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The user can input either the numerical column index or the column alphabetic label and the code will determine the correct column to filter on.